# C# Visual Studio Increment Timer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create an increment button of 10s for a countdown timer (00:00:00).  When the increment button is clicked 6 times and gets to 00:00:60 it needs to pass over to 00:01:00 etc.

Currently have (I can do the timer, just need help with the initial increment):

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = int.Parse(label4.Text);
    counter=counter+10;
    label4.Text = counter.ToString();
```

Comment: _I have exhausted google_ Great!

Comment: This explains why my google is so tired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a TimeSpan in this way:

(I am assuming that your initial text for the label is "00:00:50")

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(label4.Text);
label4.Text = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ToString();
```

**EDIT**

If you want to check if you have reached the limit of 2 hours you can split the code above in multiple lines

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(label4.Text);
if(ts.Hours == 2)
   label4.Text = "00:00:00"
else
   label4.Text = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ToString();
```

Comment: initial text for the label is 00:00:00

Comment: The important thing is being a string that can be parsed by TimeSpan.TryParse (00:00:00 is valid)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a way of setting a maximum of 2 hours in that section of code?

Comment: The TimeSpan structure has many properties. For example you can read the value of the Hours property and build your logic on that value. [See documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Tried looking through that documentation and I am finding it difficult to understand as I am so new to this.  Is there a way of setting a max of 2 hours?

Comment: No, there is no setting of a Max value, however it is simple a check on the result of the Add. Before adding the 10 seconds you could check if the current TimeStamp has the Hours property equals to 2. If true then you write code to reset the label to 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason for *modulo* existing. You could get the minutes like that:

```
int hours = counter % 60;
```

The seconds would have to be changed then as well:

```
int seconds = (int)(counter / 60);
```

It's the same for hours.

If you want to know more about Modulo or want to know what it does, take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.